# Ordering in Logistic Regression

Tags: r

In logistic regression SAS has the option to model 1 rather than 0 using "descending" option. Is there any method in R, where we can do the same thing?

The code I'm using is the following:

```
glm(y~x1+x2+x3, family=binomial(link="logit"), na.action=na.pass)
```

Regards,
Ari

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The option is exactly the same as modeling `1-y`, and will return the same coefficients but with a different sign. So either you put `1-y` in the model, or you just invert your coefficients :

```
Data <- data.frame(
    y = rbinom(100,1,0.5),
    x1 = rnorm(100),
    x2 = rnorm(100),
    x3 = rnorm(100)
)

mod1 <- glm(y~x1+x2+x3, family=binomial(link="logit"), 
           na.action=na.pass,data=Data)

mod2 <- glm((1-y)~x1+x2+x3, family=binomial(link="logit"),
           na.action=na.pass,data=Data)

> all.equal(coef(mod2),-coef(mod1))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: why is `abs` necessary? won't `y` be either 1 or 0?

Comment: @Ben oops... comes from copying too fast (piece of code that used `abs(y-1)`, which I changed to `1-y` but forgot to delete the `abs()` ). Thx for the catch

Comment: Thanks a lot Joris! The answer is too quick  :)